# How to count how many times checked if answer correct "Swift"

Tags: swift

I am trying a tutorial on how to do a number guessing game in Swift and we have where you put a number in a field and click a button to guess. If you are wrong a message appears and if you are right a different message appears. I would like to count how many times someone tried to answer the question and if they get to 5 times trying I would like to reply with a message like you stink at this (kidding)"Don't give up!" or whatever. Is there a way to count how many times someone has clicked that button. I see some similar posts but nothing that helps..

Comment: Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: What have you done so far? You can just manipulate your `onClickListener`

Comment: @Scar i think `onClickListener` is for android

Comment: pardon me for being too broad. I was referring to a function of your own that listens to the button whenever it is clicked. I was just using the term `onClickListener` because it's easy to understand for me at least. Sorry about that. Anyway, what have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

Declare a variable `var count:Int = 0`

And then every time you click the button, where you check is it match, add

```
count = count + 1
```

and then see when you gonna reply them the message, use if else

```
if count == 5{
    // Any message
}
```